# JQuery Mobile Div not displaying after checked box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, show-hide

I have a jquery mobile webapp and I'm trying to hide certain fields from the user unless they check a checkbox.  It's not working though.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
</fieldset>
<div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
    This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
```

nothing happens when I check the box.

Comment: Maybe `$('#mycheckbox').click` would help?

Comment: make it an answer and i'll check it.

Comment: dont use `.ready()` in jqm.

Comment: with this code change event is firing twice, so it toggles twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change() is generally used for input or textarea input fields.

For buttons, you check for click events with .click()

```
$("#mycheckbox").click(function() {...
```

Comment: `.change()` works for checkbox / radio. `.click()` doesn't always work.